# Count number of occurence of a node in a trie data structure

Tags: java, trie

I have a *trie* where each node is an object `TrieNode` like this:

```
public char content; 
public double count;
public LinkedList<TrieNode> childList;
```

I had to count the occurrence of a specific char in the trie.
I think to sum the `count` field of nodes that have `content = char` I'm looking for.

So this is what I've done:

```
int occ = occurrencesOfChar(0, root, c);

public int occurrencesOfChar(int occ, TrieNode node, char c) {
    for(TrieNode child : node.childList) {
        if(child.content == c) { 
            occ += child.count; 
        }
        occ += occurrencesOfChar(occ, child, c);
    }
    return occ;
}
```

But the result is overestimated, returns more occurences than those that actually are.
Why?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Uhm no, because in the `count` filed of each node can be a number > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding to `occ` multiple times because you're passing it as a parameter.
You should use a local variable:

```
public int occurrencesOfChar(TrieNode node, char c) {
    int occ = 0;
    for(TrieNode child : node.childList) {
        if(child.content == c) { 
            occ += child.count; 
        }
        occ += occurrencesOfChar(child, c);
    }
    return occ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin Broadhurst!